# Height of div doesnt change to the height of <p>

Tags: html, css

I have a paragraph of text inside a div and what I want the div to have height of the paragraph and I can't seem to get it working for some reason.

```css
.content {
  width: 960px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px
}
p {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p>Some text here</p>
</div>
```

Any idea how to fix this code so that the height of `<div class="content">` equals the height of the paragraph within. Hopefully a solution without javascript.

Comment: Overriding extra margins set around the `paragraph` by the user-agent using custom CSS should solve the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/aswc9f0j/2/

Answer (score 0):

when you add more to paragraph need to wrap words, i think you should try this

```
.content {
width: 960px;
position: relative;
float: left;
padding: 20px;
word-wrap: break-word;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are referring to the default margin that the browser adds to `<p>` tags if you do not specify anything. Just set margin:0; on the `<p>` tag to fix that. See this [codepen](http://codepen.io/codeartistgirl/pen/qaOQXN)

```
p {
  width:100%; 
  position:relative; 
  display:block; 
  clear:both;
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 100%;
  margin:0;
}
```